# Adding new line to config file using bash script

Tags: bash, redhat

is there a way to append a new line after a specific line in a config file using bash script?

For example, i want to insert a new line "Protocol 2" after "The default requires explicit activation of protocol 1" line using bash script. I would appreciate it greatly if any help is given. Thank you.

[image: sshd_conf]

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it appears to be a request for a recommendation for a tool or solution, rather than a request for assistance with your own code. This makes your question off-topic for StackOverflow. If that assessment was incorrect, and you do indeed want help writing your own code, then please [add your work so far to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45265809/edit) and I'll retract my close vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -i /etc/ssh/sshd_config -e '/# The default requires explicit activation of protocol 1/a Protocol 2'
```

(Please post text files as text, not as images.)